# How to test a Java application on Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos

Admittedly this may not be fully related to programming. However I still believe the crowd on SO will be the best to answer since it is related to testing of software and deployment.

My company develops a commercial Java application. We would like to test out this application on Mac OS X (client edition).

Mac OS X is not a big platform for us currently. We've only had a single request. So we don't want to invest in Apple hw simply for the purpose of some minor testing. Our application is pure Java but since we (normally) bundle it with a private JRE there are Mac OS X specific issues that we would like to test.

For other platforms (i.e. various Windows versions, various Linux distros, Solaris x86, etc) we simply test it in VirtualBox and this has worked fine for us so far.

Enter Mac OS X.  How do we create a Mac OS X environment simply for the purpose of testing? (without having any Apple hw). I'm under the impression that this is not possible without breaking all sorts of Apple license rules?

We are willing to invest a few dollars in an OS license if that is truly required but certainly not willing to buy any hw. For all the other OS'es mentioned we haven't actually had to pay any OS license cost, nor invest in any hw. What can be done as far as Mac OS X goes ?

(note:  whatever you suggest has to be legal, we don't want to break any licensing rules)

### Final Update

I've accepted [Ian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27754187/1504556) not because it was the answer I hoped for but because it points to service(s) I wasn't aware existed. The only problem I see with such in-the-cloud-service is that it is locked to a certain version of Mac OS X. For the other OS'es we maintain VDisks of various versions of the same OS (e.g. Win7 and Win8) so that we can test on the platform where the user reports a problem. It also enables us to create installation instructions that are more targeted to the actual version.

Comment: have you tried to test your app on virtual machines with MacOS?

Comment: @RafaelOsipov You can't install a Mac VM legally. It has to be an Apple hardware.

Comment: @adarshr even I have Mac OS purchased?

Comment: Yes, I believe that's what the licence says. There are ways to install a Mac VM on a Windows hardware, for example. But then that'll make it a Hackintosh immediately.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov You don't purchase Mac OS, you license it.

Comment: This page tells you how to do it, and talks about buying an OSX license as well, but whether you legally HAVE to run it on a mac or not, I've no idea. http://lifehacker.com/5938332/how-to-run-mac-os-x-on-any-windows-pc-using-virtualbox

Comment: I do suggest Mac Mini if you don't want to burn your pocket!

Comment: Take a look at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107324/is-installing-mavericks-on-hackintosh-legal too.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I understand that I purchase a license, not the software itself.

Comment: Guys. Buying hw doesn't solve any problem. Although my company is small we do rotating support out of three different locations. Buying (and installing/supporting) physical Apple hw for all these locations is simply not economically viable. It is not just about the purchase cost of a single hw piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS X can only (legally) be run on Apple hardware but there are services such as http://www.macincloud.com that allow you to "rent" such hardware and pay by the hour for just the time you actually spend testing on Mac.

Comment: Thanks for link. Very interesting. However this is for the *server* version of Mac OS X. Does that make any difference? (I'm not familiar with Mac OS X)

Comment: @nolan6000 not really, the [server version](https://www.apple.com/uk/osx/server/) of OS X is just an add-on to the desktop version.

Answer (score 4):

If it has to be legal, then you **must** go buy or lease some Apple hardware and purchase a license for OS X (you don't buy the software, just a license). That is the only way you'll be able to legally test on Mac OS X.